# How to filter for 'any value' in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering

Strange question but how to do I filter such that all rows are returned for a dataframe? For example, say you have the following dataframe:

```
Pts <- floor(runif(20, 0, 4))
Name <- c(rep("Adam",5), rep("Ben",5), rep("Charlie",5), rep("Daisy",5))

df <- data.frame(Pts, Name)
```

And say you want to set up a predetermined filter for this dataframe, for example:

```
Ptsfilter <- c("2", "1")
```

Which you will then run through the dataframe, to get your new filtered dataframe

```
dffil <- df[df$Pts %in% Ptsfilter, ]
```

At times, however, you don't want the dataframe to be filtered at all, and in the interests of automation and minimising workload, you don't want to have to go back and remove/comment-out every instance of this filter. You just want to be able to adjust the `Ptsfilter` value such that no rows will be filtered out of the dataframe, when that line of code is run.

I have experimented/guesses with things like:

```
Ptsfilter <- c("")
Ptsfilter <- c(" ")
Ptsfilter <- c()
```

to no avail.

Is there a value I can enter for `Ptsfilter` that will achieve this goal?

Comment: I guess you want to use `%in%` instead of `==`.  Did you meant `if(any(df$Pts %in% Ptsfilter)) df`

Comment: `Ptsfilter <- unique(df$Pts)`?

Comment: yes @akrun my mistake

Comment: @akrun I'm not sure on the significance of the second part of your comment though.

Comment: I commented that because I didn't quite understand what you were looking for.  Have you tried scoa's suggestion?

Comment: @akrun I'm trying to enter a value for `Ptsfilter` so that the dataframe remains the same as it was before. Sometimes I don't want filter to any values out and I don't want to have to enter all the values e.g. `c("1", "2", "3", "4")` and I don't want to have erase the line of code which filters the values `df[df$Pts %in% Ptsfilter, ]`

Comment: So, wouldn't scoa's suggestion work, i.e. `df[!df$Pts %in% unique(df$Pts),]`

Comment: @akrun it has to be an adjustment to the `Ptsfilter` argument, this is a centrally held variable that is used across a number of scripts. I might be misunderstanding what that your suggested argument does, but I'm not sure it achieves what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to define a function to do this for you.

```
filterDF = function(df,filter){
    if(length(filter)>0){
         return(df[df$Pts %in% filter, ])
     }
    else{
        return(df)
    }
    }
```

Comment: I think this might be the way to go, thanks. I will report back.